# How to fetch onNavigationItemSelected() values in onMapReady() in android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio

I am trying to give location coordinates for each item listed in the navigation drawer and point it on the google map.

How do it fetch the lat and long that I assign to a variable in onNavigationItemSelected() to onMapReady()?

```
//This is were I assign the coordiantes
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    double lat = 0;
    double lon = 0;

    if (id == R.id.redBuilding){
        /*lat = 13.010982;
        lon = 80.235444;

        String latitude = Double.toString(lat);
        String longitude = Double.toString(lon);
        latLong = latitude+"/"+longitude; */
    }

    if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

I want to fetch the assigned coordinates in this method to point it on the map:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
LatLng latLon = new LatLng(13.0827, 80.2707);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLon).title("Marker is in Chennai.").snippet("India"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLon));
}
```

I am using only one activity, where the map is in a Fragment.

Comment: Is the method `onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)` in a fragment?

Comment: Are you loading map in a different fragment ? Or loading the map fragment in the activity

Comment: @SifatOshan, no.

Comment: @tahsinRupam, I am loading the map in a fragment which I am display in the main activity itself.

Comment: You can use an interface to send the LatLng value to the fragment and update the map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use `onMapReady` if you want change marker. You can just save your marker when you initialize your map then change it each time that the user select an item.

```
private Marker marker;

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    LatLng latLon = new LatLng(13.0827, 80.2707);
    marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLon).title("Marker is in Chennai.").snippet("India"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLon));
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    double lat = 0;
    double lon = 0;

    if (id == R.id.redBuilding){
        lat = 13.010982;
        lon = 80.235444;

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(lat, lon));
        marker.setPosition(new LatLng(lat, lon));
        marker.setTitle("your new title");
    }

    if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@Guillaume:

Runtime exception caused:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
                  at mca.annauniv.ceg.MainActivity.a(Unknown Source)
                  at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$1.a(Unknown Source)
                  at android.support.v7.view.menu.h.a(Unknown Source)
                  at android.support.v7.view.menu.u.a(Unknown Source)
                  at android.support.v7.view.menu.j.b(Unknown Source)
                  at android.support.v7.view.menu.h.a(Unknown Source)
                  at android.support.design.internal.c$1.onClick(Unknown Source)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19330)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: When do you have this error ? When you select your redBuilding item ? If yes, be sure that your map is initialize (map display with marker "Marker is in Chennai.")

Comment: Thanks @Guillaume. It works. Thank you all for your distinguished contribution.

Answer (score 1):

if both onNavigationItemSelected() and onMapReady() methods are in the same activity then you can easily fetch the values by making variable global. if they are at different activity then you can use model or intent .